# How to get Original Bitmap size after loading URL in ImageLoader | Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, universal-image-loader

Greetings!!!
Hope you guys are doing Great!!!

I am working with [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), i need to get the original Bitmap from the URL.

Here is my code -

```
    imageLoaderNew.loadImage(bean.getPostMedia().get(i).getUrl(), optionsPostImg,
       new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
       @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                                      View view,
                                     Bitmap loadedImage) {
     // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
                                                      }
                                      });
```

The Height and Width of `loadedImage` is **not same** as the Height and Width of original Bitmap.

My Original Image Height Width is 2208,1108 but the Image Loader are not giving the Original Bitmap.

Here is the Configuration of Image Loader  -

```
  optionsPostImg = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.post_img_default) //
                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.post_img_default)
                    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.post_img_default)

                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .considerExifParams(true)
                    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)

                    .build();
```

Please let me know, how to get the original Bitmap.

Comment: Just download the file. There is no original bitmap to begin with. Only an original file.

Comment: But if i will download the file, it will consume lot of memory.

Comment: No nothing. Maybe 8192 bytes for a buffer in a loop. Thats all.

Comment: I am using this inside a Recyler view, there will be 1000s of Images.

Comment: Then why do you use/want such big impossible resolutions? No Android device can handle that. And in a recyclerview why would you need that resolution for every item?

Comment: I need to do some cropping inside the Recycler view, and Original Bitmap is required to create Cropped Bitmap.

Comment: If you keep talking about 'original Bitmap' then i have nothing more to say.